# Kaprekar's constant algorithm in c#

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have implemented the kaprekar's constant algorithm in c#, and I want your feedback.

Here is how the algorithm works:

- it takes a number of 4 digits (e.g: 5823)
- we order that number in ascendent and descendent order, which gives as two numbers (e.g: 8532 and 2358).
- we subtract the larger number from the smaller number (e.g: 8532 - 2358 = 6174)
- we repeat this operation until the difference is equal to 6174.

Example:

step 1:

```
 number = 8532
    cpt = 0 // the number of repeatation util the number became equal to 6174.
    1) asc  = 2358
    2) desc = 8532
    3) Difference = 6174  
    4) cpt++ 
    5) Repeating above steps as difference is not equal to number.
```

step2:

```
 number = 6174
     1) asc  = 1467
     2) desc = 7641
     3) Difference = 6174
     4) c++  
     5) return cpt and stopping here as difference is equal to number.
```

Here is my Code:

1- recursive method:

```
   int KaprekarsConstant(int num, int target)
        {
            if (num.ToString().Length != 4)
                throw new ArgumentException();

            var desendingOrder = num.ToString().OrderByDescending(a => a);
            var acendingOrder = num.ToString().OrderBy(a => a);

            int maxPart = int.Parse(new string(desendingOrder.ToArray()));
            int minPart = int.Parse(new string(acendingOrder.ToArray()));

            var diff = maxPart - minPart;
            if (diff == target) return 1;
            return 1+ KaprekarsConstant(diff, target);
        }
```

2- non-recursive method:

```
 int KaprekarsConstant2(int num, int target)
            {
                int cpt = 0;
                if (num.ToString().Length != 4)
                    throw new ArgumentException();

                while (true)
                {
                    var desendingOrder = num.ToString().OrderByDescending(a => a);
                    var acendingOrder = num.ToString().OrderBy(a => a);

                    int maxPart = int.Parse(new string(desendingOrder.ToArray()));
                    int minPart = int.Parse(new string(acendingOrder.ToArray()));

                    var diff = maxPart - minPart;
                    cpt++;
                    if (diff == target) return cpt;
                    num = diff;
                }
            }
```

Code test:

```
  public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(KaprekarsConstant(6174, 6174)); //cpt =1
            Console.WriteLine(KaprekarsConstant(3524, 6174)); //cpt =3
            Console.WriteLine(KaprekarsConstant(2324, 6174)); //cpt =3
            Console.WriteLine(KaprekarsConstant(9812, 6174)); //cpt =2
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Both answers already mention to avoid `num.ToString()` because its more efficient to avoid it, but also could be a bug if `num = -123` since it's a 3 digit number but the negative sign counts as the 4th character.

Comment: @RickDavin that's right I did not think of it, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is known that you'll only be dealing with numbers from 1000 to 9998(9999 is invalid since at least one digit must be different), you can work this problem without converting to strings and at the same time improve the speed quite considerably.  It could look something like this:

```
static readonly int KeprekarsConstant = 6174;
public static int KaprekarsConst(int num)
{
    if (num >= 10000 || num < 1000)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("'num' nust have 4 digits");
    }
    if(num % 11 == 0 && (num/11) % 101 == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int diff = 0;
    int count = 0;
    do
    {
        diff = KapDiff(num);
        ++count;
        num = diff;
    } while (diff != KeprekarsConstant);
    return count;
}
static int KapDiff(int num)
{
    int[] digits =
        {
            num / 1000,
            (num/100) % 10,
            (num/10) % 10,
            num % 10
        };
    Array.Sort(digits);
    int numAsc = digits[0] * 1000 + digits[1] * 100 + digits[2] * 10 + digits[3];
    int numDes = digits[3] * 1000 + digits[2] * 100 + digits[1] * 10 + digits[0];
    int diff = numDes - numAsc;
    return diff;
}
```

Comment: That was a good optimization, thanks!

Comment: Why not just `const int KeprekarsConstant = 6174;`?

Comment: Mostly personal preference.

Answer (score 3):

- 6174 is Kaprekar Constant, I don't know why you're using it as an
  input argument  while it should be within the method. So, you'll only
  need to pass one int argument.
- there is no need to call `ToString` to get the length of the integer.
  You can check the integer range instead. So, this `num.ToString().Length != 4` can be converted to `num >= 1000 && num <= 9999`.
- using `LINQ` is fine, but in your case, I don't see a need of that. As you have fixed input length (4 digits), you can simply converted to string, then just do `str[index]` where the index would be a range of 0 to 3.
- why are you using `while(true)` while you could enforce kaprekar's
  constant condition by using `while(diff != 6174)`.
- No need for recursive method.

here is a standard version :

```
int KaprekarsConstant(int num)
{

    // zero == zero
    if (num == 0) { return 0; }

    // if num is not between 1000 and 9999 throw exception
    if(num >= 1000 && num <= 9999) { throw new ArgumentException(); }

    // will be used inside the loop
    var diff = num;

    // number of repeatation
    var numberOfRepeatation = 0;

    do // do it at least once.
    {
        //to array 
        var digitsAsc = new int[4];

        for (var x = 0; x < 4; x++)
        {
            digitsAsc[x] = diff % 10;
            diff /= 10;
        }

        // sort the elements in the array to ascendent order
        Array.Sort(digitsAsc);

        //now, digitsAsc array is in ascedent order, we will resorted into descendent order
        var digitsDesc = new int[4];

        for (var x = 0; x < 4; x++)
        {
            digitsDesc[x] = digitsAsc[3 - x];
        }

        // convert them to int
        var asce = int.Parse(string.Join(string.Empty, digitsAsc));

        var desc = int.Parse(string.Join(string.Empty, digitsDesc));

        diff = desc - asce;

        numberOfRepeatation++;

    }
    while (diff != 6174);

    return numberOfRepeatation;
}
```

if you're into `LINQ`, here is `LINQ` version :

```
int KaprekarsConstant(int num)
{
    // zero == zero
    if (num == 0) { return 0; }

    // if num is not between 1000 and 9999 throw exception
    if(num >= 1000 && num <= 9999) { throw new ArgumentException(); }

    // will be used inside the loop
    var diff = num;

    // number of repeatation
    var numberOfRepeatation = 0;

    do // do it at least once.
    {
        //to ascedent array 
        var digitsAsc = Array
            .ConvertAll(diff.ToString().ToCharArray(), x => (int)char.GetNumericValue(x))
            .OrderBy(x=>x)
            .ToArray();

        //now, digitsAsc array is in ascedent order, we will resorted into descendent order by calling Reverse;
        var digitsDesc = digitsAsc.Reverse().ToArray();

        // convert them to string (this is similar to string.Join)
        var asce = digitsAsc
            .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (x, y) => x.Append(x.Length == 0 ? string.Empty : string.Empty).Append(y))
            .ToString();

        var desc = digitsDesc
            .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (x, y) => x.Append(x.Length == 0 ? string.Empty : string.Empty).Append(y))
            .ToString();

        diff = int.Parse(desc) - int.Parse(asce);

        numberOfRepeatation++;

    }
    while (diff != 6174);

    return numberOfRepeatation;
}
```

Comment: num mod 10 != 4 has nothing to do with number of digits.

Comment: @slepic actually, I'm not sure why I did that in the first place !, I have changed it to `num >= 1000 && num <= 9999`.